# Android studio not giving suggestions from android-src.jar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've downloaded android-src.jar and added it as a dependency to another project, but the code completion will only show the something like com.google.android.mms.pdu but no suggestions come after that for classes.

I've tried various dependencies, but none of them work. I've also tried tried Invalidate cache/Restart.

When I look through the library and view one of its classes, it's telling me it can't resolve symbols for classes that are clearly there.

Answer (score 0):

These classes belong to Android framework, Platform classes can refer to other **package private** classes and you could not see its actual compiled class. Only symbols exposed by package designer could be seen.